# How do I find a tetris shape from a bitmask value over a matrix

Tags: c#, graph-algorithm, tetris

I have a 7x5 matrix with several bitmask values, each corresponding to a particular Tetris piece uniquely colored and positioned over the 7x5 array. I need to get the position shape & name(1 out of 19 basic named Tetris shapes) of the Tetris piece based on the selected bitmask value (see sample image below). I can easily draw blocks over a 7x5 matrix by mapping the 1's and 0's to get the shape and position, but I'm running short of thoughts to get the name of the piece.

I need to do this in C# and I'm pretty much clueless with a possible solution so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: How do you store the shape as a bitmask?

Comment: It looks like the upper left most box is 2^0 and it works from left to right from there. The pictured image is therefore 2^12 + 2^17 + 2^18 + 2^23.

Comment: Petelids is right! The value is calculated from upper leftmost box starting with 2^0.